Issue with copy stage in multi-stage dockerfile
current file structure (viewed from project directory)

docker-compose.yml
docker

local

node.Dockerfile




package1

package.json
package-lock.json


package2

package.json



In the dockerfile I have
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

ARG PACKAGE=package1

FROM node:18-slim AS build-package1

WORKDIR /opt/app/package1
COPY package1/package.json ./
RUN npm install

FROM node:18-slim AS build-package2

WORKDIR /opt/app/package2
COPY package2/package.json .
RUN npm install

FROM build-${PACKAGE} AS selected

FROM node:18-slim AS final
COPY --from=selected /opt/app/${PACKAGE}/node_modules ./node_modules

CMD node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service build --watch

in the docker-compose.yml I have the following section:
package1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/local/node.Dockerfile
      args:
        PACKAGE: package1
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - NODE_ENV=development
    env_file:
      - package1.env
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/app/

The error I get when running docker compose build package1 is:
 => ERROR [package1 build-package1 3/4] COPY package1/package.json /.                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
------
 > [package1 build-package1 3/4] COPY package1/package.json /.:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref d13f7eee-5599-4ff4-afe2-98aa8fdf8e98::6cyzhntidjqeql84qefo98r5i: "/package1/package.json": not found

I have tried to change to COPY ./package1/package.json and I checked the paths multiple times. In terminal I am also in the right location. Is there some obvious syntax mistake I am missing here?
Am I using docker multi-stage builds wrong in some sense? My intention is to have one dockerfile to maintain instead of two. Also I thought this would lower disk space usage as docker is only caching one docker image. An accepted answer could also be an explanation how this dockerfile compares to building the containers from two files

As you've shown it, it seems like this should work – the build: { context: . } sets the directory containing the Compose file as the build context, and package1/package.json is relative to that (subdirectories only, no parent or sibling directories), which matches your file structure.  I can say for the last paragraph that this unusual file structure results in no space savings, you will get two disjoint images that only share the Node base image, and the result is identical to split package1/Dockerfile and package2/Dockerfile.

I suspected that I made all this effort for not much gain :D Thanks for the comment and the confirmation

At some point, COPY --from=selected /opt/app/${PACKAGE}/node_modules ./node_modules will fail because the PACKAGE arg is not defined within that stage, but you aren't getting to that yet. Like David says, your description of the compose file and directory structure shouldn't experience that error, so start looking for a .dockerignore file, typos, hidden file extensions, case sensitivity, and similar errors.
